# Centralized management of app.config parts for self-hosted .NET services

Tags: c#, .net, configuration, cloud, app-config

What will be the best way to handle these scenarios, if they are not one-time, but regular:

- Self-hosted services on a quite a bunch of machines are needed to be repointed to different database in a centralized way. So it requires changing app.configs and restarting services.
- All services need to get new logging configuration ( for example ), say update section in App.config and restart

Of course this can be automated using powershell, but there definitely are tools for that. I know, that some companies use Configuration Management Systems for that - like [Salt](http://saltstack.com/), [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/), [Chef](https://www.chef.io/chef/) or [Puppet](https://puppetlabs.com/), but are they suited for this kind of task.

I also now about Java solution [Spring cloud config](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/), but haven't found something like this for .NET

Comment: this was sort of answered on SuperUser  - http://superuser.com/a/1057345/282134